# Having turtle-specific variables from two different breeds of the same name

Tags: netlogo

I have a quick question.

Say I wanted to have two breeds, defined by
    breed [humans human]
    breed [mosquitoes mosquito]
and wanted to have turtle specific variables **of the same name** for those breeds. So

```
humans-own
[
  infected
]
mosquitoes-own
[
  infected
]
```

and I wanted to call the procedure later (pretend that a setup has been made, with infected to be set at the initial boolean value false), like

```
to infect
  set infected true
end
```

. I understand that it would call set both mosquito and human-specific 'infected' variables to be true, but what if I wanted to do this:

```
to specific-infect
  if turtles = humans
  [
    set infected true
  ]
  if turtles = mosquitoes
  [
    set infected true
  ]
end
```

. Would it check if the turtle was human, and if it was, then set human-specific 'infected' to true, or do both? Essentially, what I am asking is that can you have turtle-specific variables of the same name and have it be viable for code?

Comment: There's no problem. `set infected ...` will do the right thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breeds can certainly have "own" variables with the same name, but as with turtles in general, essentially only a breed can change the value of one of its variables, and you need to ask it to so.  So, if you wanted to set infected to true for all humans and to false for all mosquitoes, you would do it as follows:

```
ask humans [set infected true]
ask mosquitoes [set infected false]
```

Or, for just certain humans

```
ask humans with [some characteristic] [set infected true]
```

Similarly you would have the agents in the breeds each report the values of their variables.

```
show [infected] of human with [some characteristic]
```

Check out the NetLogo primitives `ask`, `of`, and `with` for some examples.

Answer (score 0):

at the individual turtle level, the turtle 'knows' the own breed. so you can add

```
if breed = humans [do human infection thing]
if breed = musquitos [do musquito infection thing]
```